# Joomla Blank Template for Fresh Development?

Tags: css, joomla

I have Joomla Version 1.6.3 installed on my web hosting provider. I would like to do some fresh designing from a clean/blank slate of a template. I see the Joomla website has a vast amount of templates to choose from. Are there any clean/blank templates with no formatting? Then, how do I go about slowly introducing my own CSS styles? If someone could point me in a good direction, I would much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the beginning documentation for 1.6:
http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_1.6_Template_Tutorial

However - you would probably be better served looking at the 1.5 (linked on the bottom of that page) as it's complete.  Also, you should update your Joomla version - I believe they are at 1.7+ these days.

Most people typically start with the default template (milkyway I believe) or copy/modify the Beez template because it's pretty straight forward html/css manipulation.